# ExpandableContentControl not resize on content resize

Tags: silverlight

On the treeview expand and collapse the ExpandableContentControl not resize.Following is the code for the same :

```
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                        
                    MinWidth="225"                         
                    Height="Auto" 
                    >

            <layoutToolkit:AccordionItem  Header="A" >                                    
                <controls:TreeView Margin="5" SizeChanged="TreeView_SizeChanged" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" UseLayoutRounding="True">
                    <controls:TreeViewItem Header="Controls">
                        <controls:TreeViewItem Header="AutoCompleteBox"/>
                        <controls:TreeViewItem Header="Expander"/>
                        <controls:TreeViewItem Header="NumericUpDown"/>
                    </controls:TreeViewItem>
                    <controls:TreeViewItem Header="Layout">
                        <controls:TreeViewItem Header="DockPanel"/>
                        <controls:TreeViewItem Header="WrapPanel"/>
                        <controls:TreeViewItem Header="Viewbox"/>
                    </controls:TreeViewItem>
                    <controls:TreeViewItem Header="Charting">
                        <controls:TreeViewItem Header="ColumnSeries"/>
                        <controls:TreeViewItem Header="LineSeries"/>
                        <controls:TreeViewItem Header="PieSeries"/>
                    </controls:TreeViewItem>
                </controls:TreeView>

        </layoutToolkit:AccordionItem>


        <layoutToolkit:AccordionItem Content="item 2" Header="B -  long header"/>
        <system:String>regular string item 3</system:String>

    </layoutToolkit:Accordion>
```

waiting for your valuable thoughts.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. See http://forums.silverlight.net/t/97918.aspx/1/10. You can find some workarounds there.